# spring boot with multiple database - both of them have the same schema name and table name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, multiple-databases

I have two databases but both of them contain the same table name and schema name.
so when I am creating the entity class how can I specify which class should connect to the first database and the other one to the second database?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does it for you. All you have to do is to show Spring that you need 2 datasources.

For this, you have to do:

1. Create 2 separate configuration classes.
2. In each, you have to declare beans: dataSource, entityManager, and transactionalManager.
3. Mark datasource beans with @ConfigurationProperties annotation with "prefix" which separates datasource props in your properties/yml file.
4. Configuration class has to be marked with @EnableJpaRepositories annotation. In the parameters of the annotation you have to specify "basePackages" - the value should lead to your entity model (ex: "com.myprj.dao.entity.user"),
   "entityManagerFactoryRef" as the name of your entityManager bean,
   "transactionManagerRef" as the name of your transactionalManager bean.

Spring will manage the rest of the work.